# Error while redeploying WAR in Jenkins,how to solve?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

**i am running two tomcat server simultaneously on port 8090 & 8081.
8090 connected with Jenkins-staging job 
& 8081 connected with Jenkins-production job
8090 running perfectly. but 8081 has the following error :**

Started by user admin
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-to-prod
Copied 1 artifact from "maven3-project" build number 69
Deploying C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-to-prod\webapp\target\webapp.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context 
  Redeploying [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-to-prod\webapp\target\webapp.war]
  Undeploying [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-to-prod\webapp\target\webapp.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to undeploy [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\deploy-to-prod\webapp\target\webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:177)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1835)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Program Files\APACHE\apache-tomcat-8.5.37-production\webapps\webapp.war]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:441)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:129)
    ... 18 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Program Files\APACHE\apache-tomcat-8.5.37-production\webapps\webapp.war]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:441)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:177)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1835)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

**# i have already changed server.xml file:**
`<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8444" />`

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8084" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" />
```

`

Comment: You are under Windows which does not allow an open file to be deleted.  The WAR file is open for some reason.

Comment: Did you try to set `antiResourceLocking="true"` in context element? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html